# Cannot find name ‘HockeyApp’

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to use the report system from hockey app using this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-hockeyapp
but when i try to inject this module into `app.component.ts` constructor I get error, why?

```
import { HockeyApp } from 'ionic-hockeyapp';

constructor(public platform: Platform,
    public app: App,
    public hockeyApp: HockeyApp) { }
```

error at the last line on `HockeyApp`

and I have imported HockeyApp in `app.module.ts` and made it a `provider`

Comment: Have you installed it via npm? Is it in your package.json file?

Comment: yes and yes, and plugin too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in a version 0.1.6 of hockeyapp and was fixed in 0.1.7.